# Delete from wp_posts where (string starts with <a href="consistent-inconsistent"></a>)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wildcard

Basically, I have a thousands of links that all contain Search The Site. (xxxxxx being the varied text).

If I can just get rid of the opening anchor tag, I can go in and delete every instance of the closing tag no problem.

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for `delete from table where left(string, 38)='<a href=“consistent-inconsistent”></a>'`

if you want to truncate that part of the string, just use substring_index or replace

`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, 'leading string', -1)` removes leading string

`SELECT REPLACE('string', 'part you want to replace', 'what to replace with')` replaces substring with something. Replace with "" to delete.